# Every time I turn on my VPN I am prompted for username and password

Tags: macos, network, vpn

Every time I turn on a VPN I added manually to Network preferences a password prompt appears

[image]

> **macOS wants to make changes. Enter an administrator's name and password to allow this.**
>
> macOS wants to use the "System" keychain.

My account is the administrator (and only) account on my Macbook. I have to enter my username and password to continue and finally the VPN turns on.

This is a pain to have to repeat every single time I want to turn the VPN on.

How can I allow the VPN to just turn on without requiring password input?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)